# Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

[image]

```
// src/Login.tsx
const Login = () => {
  <h1>Success</h1>;
};

export default Login;
```

```
// src/Router.tsx
export default () => {
  const CLIENT_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_KAKAO_API_KEY;
  const REDIRECT_URI = "http://localhost:3000/api/user/kakao/callback";
  const KAKAO_AUTH_URL = `https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=code`;

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <h1>
              <a href={KAKAO_AUTH_URL}>
                <Login />
              </a>
            </h1>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/oauth/kakao/callback">
            <Auth />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/profile">
            <Profile />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I see an error.. 'Login' cannot be used as a JSX component.Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.

I tried to reference it on here, but I can't find a solution. What should I do?

Comment: where is login used ? in the component ?

Comment: I think.."Login" is just inside the src folder.

Comment: Can you add the code of that file too ?

Comment: The error is in the `Login` component :S

Comment: I added Login.tsx

Comment: `() => { <h1>...</h1> }` doesn't return anything either ad a `return` or remove the braces `{}`

Answer (score 3):

Your login component needs return anything.

```
// src/Login.tsx
const Login = () => {
  return <h1>Success</h1>;
};
```

Comment: oh!!! my terrible mistake..thank you very much...